# Implement a retry policy in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the simplest way to implement a retry policy in asp.net core ? The idea is simple, if some particular type of exceptions is raised ( say sql deadlock ), we retry the httprequest for a maximum of N times.

I use a middleware for som custom authentication, I don't know if a middleware is the best choice for this kind of mechanism ( I'm new to the pipeline architecture, I have read that there are several types of components : Singletons, per-request etc ..).

UPDATE:
Sql deadlock is given here just as an example, my application has only restful webservices in it, each request is very short and runs entirely in a Serializable Sql Transaction ( there is no other side effects which I can't rollback like sending email or deleting a File... ).
Because I'm using transactions, and because I can't garantee that my transactions will always use the tables in the same order ( It depends on who calls the webservices ), deadlock is inavoidable, so I need to have a retry policy of all the httprequest.
( The question is not about transactions and deadlocks but how to implement a retry police in asp.net core )

Comment: http doesn't have a retry policy.

Comment: I used Polly Library. More info @ http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekPollyWannaFluentlyExpressTransientExceptionHandlingPoliciesInNET.aspx and https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: @LukeHutton, did you use Polly for an ASP.NET Core project, or an ASP.NET "classic" project? Does Polly support ASP.NET Core yet?

Comment: @MichaelMcCarthy looks like an alpha release available on nuget, and it's high priority, see https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-Roadmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot on what level you want to retry. Let's say a DB operation fails. Do you want to retry the entire request (with all its overhead) or just that operation?

Based on the level you want the retry to happen at, you might find one solution or another more appropriate.

You can always retry at middleware level by reinvoking the components that follow that middleware in the pipeline but what's very important to remember is that you can't blindly retry (I would be afraid to do that) because the code could not be designed for that...

Like Luke Hutton suggested, probably Polly is something that you can use.

Answer (score 8):

You can use out of the box tools such as [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

> Polly is a .NET 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 / PCL library that allows developers to express transient exception and fault handling policies such as Retry, Retry Forever, Wait and Retry or Circuit Breaker in a fluent manner.

In your particular case, example could be:

```
Policy
  .Handle<SqlException>(ex => ex.Number == 1205) // sql deadlock
  .Retry(3, (exception, retryCount) =>
  {
     // do something 
  });
```

Although I am not sure how your sql deadlock and web requests relate to each other. I would think your would retry a http request in response to an http status code. For example, the following policy and then add how to handle those conditions:

```
Policy
  .HandleResult<HttpStatusCode>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
  .OrResult<HttpStatusCode>(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know it exists, I will use it for my middleware.